# Replace all characters of string to asterisks except first and last characters in PHP

Tags: php, string, function

How to replace all characters of string to asterisks except first and last characters in PHP?

For example `test` should become `t**t` and `profanity` become `p******y` and so on

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: use `substr` to get the first and last characters; then append those with `(length($string) - 2)` asterisks in between.

Comment: I have update my answere [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090072/replace-all-characters-of-string-to-asterisks-except-first-and-last-characters-i/16090361#16090361) check it!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
function get_starred($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);

    return substr($str, 0, 1).str_repeat('*', $len - 2).substr($str, $len - 1, 1);
}


$myStr = 'YourName';
echo get_starred($myStr); //should show Y******e
```

Answer (score 4):

Here a small function:

```
function asterisks($toConvert) {
    $astNumber = strlen($toConvert) - 2;
    return substr($toConvert, 0, 1) . str_repeat("*", $astNumber) . substr($toConvert, -1);
}

$tempString= 'teststring';
echo asterisks($tempString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "test";
$len = strlen($str);
$str1 = '';
for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
   if($i != 0 && $i != ($len-1)) {
       $str1 .= '*';
   } else {
       $str1 .= $str[$i];
   }
}

echo $str1;
```

Use the above code. This will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$split_string = str_split($start_string);
$i = 1;
while ( $i < count($split_string)-2 ){
    split_string[$i] = '*';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will replace the first and last like `*bcdefghijklm*` characters from variable `$text`;

```
$text = 'abcdefghijklmn';
$count = strlen($text)-1;
echo str_replace(array($text[0], $text[$count]), '*', $text);
```